# simple .htaccess internal rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess

I want to do this simple internal write :

```
http://localhost/icore4/t1/js/GeneralJs.js
```

to

```
http://localhost/icore4/js/GeneralJs.js
```

htaccess location

```
icore4/.htaccess
```

htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$2 [NC,L]
```

bottomline, I want to get rid of t1 and put it in the query string.
As of now, I am bothered about getting rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this question, my question only which solves the same problem

[htaccess rewrite and recursive internal redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449419/htaccess-rewrite-and-recursive-internal-redirects)