# htaccess rewrite and recursive internal redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do a simple internal htaccess rewrite which is

```
http://localhost/icore4/t9/module/ac/Main.php?do=subject_add
```

to

```
http://localhost/icore4/module/ac/Main.php?do=subject_add
```

I am using the following rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]*/)(.*)$ $2 [NC,L]
```

I keep getting page not found error.

When I look at the rewrite log I see that the rewriting is happening recursively.
That is

```
http://localhost/icore4/t9/module/ac/Main.php?do=subject_add
```

to

```
http://localhost/icore4/module/ac/Main.php?do=subject_add
```

to

```
http://localhost/icore4/ac/Main.php?do=subject_add
```

to

```
http://localhost/icore4/Main.php?do=subject_add
```

LOG

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34ad8e8/initial] (1) pass through /icore4/t9/module/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34ad8e8/initial] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] add path info postfix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/t9 -> F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/t9/module/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34ad8e8/initial] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] strip per-dir prefix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/t9/module/ac/Main.php -> t9/module/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34ad8e8/initial] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] applying pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9]*/)(.*)$' to uri 't9/module/ac/Main.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34ad8e8/initial] (2) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] rewrite 't9/module/ac/Main.php' -> 'module/ac/Main.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34ad8e8/initial] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] add per-dir prefix: module/ac/Main.php -> F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/module/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34ad8e8/initial] (2) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] strip document_root prefix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/module/ac/Main.php -> /icore4/module/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34ad8e8/initial] (1) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] internal redirect with /icore4/module/ac/Main.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3481db8/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /icore4/module/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3481db8/initial/redir#1] (1) pass through /icore4/module/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3481db8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] strip per-dir prefix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/module/ac/Main.php -> module/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3481db8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] applying pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9]*/)(.*)$' to uri 'module/ac/Main.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3481db8/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] rewrite 'module/ac/Main.php' -> 'ac/Main.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3481db8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] add per-dir prefix: ac/Main.php -> F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3481db8/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] strip document_root prefix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/ac/Main.php -> /icore4/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3481db8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] internal redirect with /icore4/ac/Main.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /icore4/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (1) pass through /icore4/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] add path info postfix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/ac -> F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] strip per-dir prefix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/ac/Main.php -> ac/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] applying pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9]*/)(.*)$' to uri 'ac/Main.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] rewrite 'ac/Main.php' -> 'Main.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] add per-dir prefix: Main.php -> F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] strip document_root prefix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/Main.php -> /icore4/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#3487118/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] internal redirect with /icore4/Main.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34895f8/initial/redir#3] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /icore4/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34895f8/initial/redir#3] (1) pass through /icore4/Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34895f8/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] strip per-dir prefix: F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/Main.php -> Main.php
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34895f8/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] applying pattern '^([A-Za-z0-9]*/)(.*)$' to uri 'Main.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2010:12:57:17 +051800] [localhost/sid#93d158][rid#34895f8/initial/redir#3] (1) [perdir F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/] pass through F:/xampp/htdocs/icore4/Main.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this recursion is supposed to happen.

After the url goes through the rewrite rule, it is again passed to the mod_rewrite engine with the same htaccess.  In you case it will always satisfy the Reg exp.

You may put a rewrite cond to avoid the same, something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !t=(.*)
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*/)(.*)$ $2?%{QUERY_STRING}&t=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a stricter pattern if you can, like for example limiting the first segment to two characters:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/(.+) $1 [L]
```

Or by specifying the number of following segments:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9]+/([^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+)$ $1 [L]
```